# Decrypt OpenSSL encrypted string in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, openssl

I have a string encrypted in PHP using following code

```
function encrypt($string, $publicKey)
{
    openssl_public_encrypt($string, $cryptedText, $publicKey);
    return base64_encode($cryptedText);
}
$publicKey = file_get_contents('public.crt');
$encryptedText = encrypt('Test', $publicKey);
```

This works fine in PHP, i am able to encrypt/decrypt using public/private key pair.

The encryptedText is sent to iOS application where i want to decrypt the same string, i tried with multiple approaches and nothing seems to be working, any pointer to do the following is appreciated.

- Decrypt OpenSSL encrypted string received from PHP in Objective-C
- Encrypt and send data to PHP for Decrypting (should support [openssl_private_decrypt](https://www.php.net/openssl_private_decrypt))

Comment: Seems like [this guide](http://jslim.net/blog/2013/01/05/rsa-encryption-in-ios-and-decrypt-it-using-php/) should be enough to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thanks@Jack let me try this

Comment: @Ja͢ck, your link helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this library for iOS which worked perfectly.

https://github.com/jslim89/RSA-Example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660659/how-to-implement-phps-openssl-encrypt-method-in-ios-objective-c

Comment: This is no supported anymore @ibrahim-azhar-armar